# Permission Denied with git remote add in Github Actions

Tags: git, azure, github-actions, permission-denied, git-remote

Locally I'm able to do the git deploy and push.
In my github actions the following is set after npm build has run:

```bash
cd build
git init
git config user.email 'email@email.com'
git config user.name 'github-actions - CI'
git add -A
git commit -m 'build by GA'
git remote add azure https://${{ secrets.GITUSER }}:${{ secrets.GITPW }}@<azure_local_git_url>.git
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

After this there would be a git push, but clearly the problem is with git remote add.

Cant seem to figure out whats going on.

EDIT:
In azure there is an App service, used with local git deployment, and the user and password, which is set in the secrets GITUSER and GITPW, is Application Scope level. This was used by a jenkins server where it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at the wrong place, since I'm already checked out with the sourcecode, I dont have to use git init, which was throwing the Permission Denied.

Comment: `git init` shouldn't fail in this case though: it should just say "reinitialized existing Git repository" (after doing basically nothing). So there's still some kind of mystery here, just not one that's affecting your getting things done.

Comment: Hmm, no idea then, Github Action apparently doesnt allow it. The work around was to do the git init part in a new job and I just piped the npm build folder into it.